# Virtualbox shared folders

Tags: osx-lion, ubuntu-10.04, virtualbox

I am running virtualbox in my Mac (Lion). The guest os is Ubuntu Lucid. I have installed guest additions and am trying to create a shared folder to pass files from the guest os to the host os. I can't seem to get the two to connect. When I create a shared folder it never shows up in Ubuntu.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that means that you looked in the locations specified for automatic mounting:

http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sf_mount_auto

Have you tried manually mounting it?

```
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/vboxmount/sharename && sudo mount -t vboxsf sharename /mnt/vboxmount/sharename
```

Comment: I was able to find the answer using this method. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome; I am glad that this was able to resolve your issue.  (If you think this answer is helpful, especially to others, don't forget to up-vote.)

Answer (score 0):

My only suggestion is to avoid guest tools in VirtualBox like the plague. It has been proven to be so unstable that maintainers of the Linux Kernel may throw away your bug report based only on having that driver loaded.

http://linux.slashdot.org/story/11/10/11/1845226/linux-kernel-developer-declares-virtualbox-driver-crap

You may have better luck using something a bit more conventional, like NFS.